# Laravel DB array issues

Tags: php, database, laravel

Recently installed Laravel on localhost and made a DB in PhPMyadmin. Trying to create a test user and got this error registering:

**Illuminate\Database\QueryException
Database hosts array is empty. (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `email`**

Is this a migration,.env, or config error?

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=swarzie
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=Gal%1981
```

**config**

```
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env( '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env( '3306'),
            'database' => env( 'swarzie'),
            'username' => env( 'root'),
            'password' => env( 'Gal%1981'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

Worked with php before but new to the Laravel framework. How do I correct this please?

Thank ya :)

Comment: shouldn't this be `'host' => env( 'DB_HOST'),` instead?

Comment: In fact, all but the `url` parameter have the wrong values for the `env()` function.

Comment: Thank you 2 so much for the help it means alot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your config file is setup incorrectly, please see the below snippet. I have hard coded the db password into the config file as you did but it is not a good idea to add your db password into the config file, this is OK for local development but a bad idea for production. Simply leave it out of the config file and use the .env

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'swarzie'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'Gal%1981'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

The error is being shown because the users table does not exist in the database, to initialise the database run

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: Thank ya so very much for this :)...I changed the config file to your specs then did the migration and was still having issues. After a tad bit of research I realized I had to clear cache then once I did that the migration was successful!!

Comment: No problem, please accept the answer if it helped you.